# I want to updateMany a model A then update another ref model B base on updated model A

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I have 2 models, 1 is `Coupon` and another 1 is `RedeemedCoupon` which has a reference to the `Coupon`. I also have a cron job which will run every midnight to check is the `RedeemedCoupon` expired or not. If yes then change the status from available to expired then **return the number of quantity** to the corresponding `Coupon`.

However, the mongoose `updateMany` can only return the count of updated document which not allow me refer to the original coupon and add stock quantity back.

Is there any other way can achieve this case?

```
const CouponSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            trim: true,
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 0,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

```
const RedeemedCouponSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        coupon: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Coupon",
        },
        owner: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
        expires: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
        },
        status: {
            type: Number,
            default: Constants.RedeemedCoupon.AVAILABLE,
        },
    },
```

```
// Do every midnight to check all the status of redeemedCoupons
cron.schedule(
    "0 0 * * *",
    async () => {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const redeemedCoupons = await RedeemedCoupon.updateMany(
            { expires: { $lte: currentDate } },
            {
                $set: { status: Constants.RedeemedCoupon.EXPIRED },
            }
        );
     ...
     ...
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the operations cannot be a single database call. You can get all matching documents and do a findOneAndUpdate in a for-loop. findOneAndUpdate can return the updated document.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Do every midnight to check all the status of redeemedCoupons
cron.schedule(
    "0 0 * * *",
    async () => {
        const currentDate = new Date();
        const expiredCoupons = await RedeemedCoupon.find({{ expires: { $lte: currentDate }})
        // use bluebird promise not the node js default
        await Promise.map(expiredCoupons, async function(expiredCoupon){
               expiredCoupon.status = Constants.RedeemedCoupon.EXPIRED;
               await expiredCoupon.save()
               return CouponSchema.UpdateOne(...your query based on expiredCoupon.coupon for dec quantity by one)
            })
       

    }
```

with this code you will be able to dec by 1 every time you manual reedem a coupon